# Difference between edo tensei Madara with rinnegan and Alive Madara with Rinnegan

Tags: naruto

When madara was revived, he lost his pair of rinnegan ,his reservoir of infinite chakra  and not be killed ability (being an edo tensei).

So, I know why madara wanted to be revived, but my question is , how does the ability differ in these 2 cases?

Answer (score 7):

An Edo Tensei cannot be a jinchuuriki, and so, he couldn't complete his plan by becoming the Ten Tails' jinchuuriki. That is the main reason he wanted to be revived.

Also, although very powerful, the power of a "real" Rinnegan is far superior to one of the reanimated "fake" Rinnegan. The "real" Rinnegan can summon and control the Gedo Mazo, use the **[Rinbo: Hengoku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinbo%3a_Hengoku)** technique etc.

Comment: Fitting that Madara himself would answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned by Madara Uchiha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/7639), 
as an Edo Tensei he could not be a jinchuuriki of the Ten Tails wich was needed to activate the Infinite Tsukoyomi.

Second is that he wasn't near his full power and his Rinnegan had some abilities but not as much and powerful as the Rinnegan while alive.

While being an Edo Tensei, he released himself from any kind of control the emotions, adrenaline etc., became sustained like you don't give a crap about anything. Being an Edo Tensei you just cannot fight with full dedication and fighting spirit. It's like holding back is part of your nature.

Also the risk of being sealed while in his Edo Tensei state would always be a risk.

Answer (score -2):

Because he knew that remaining in such an unimportant inefficient state couldn't accomplish anything remotely significant and it was kinda idiotic to still be in such an extremely weakening state for him since Madara had such an immensely glorious goal of the highest calibre to achieve. Also, actually in fact Madara himself is million times more vastly powerful in his fully-living body than in his half-dead paper-maché-like like living corpse state.

The real/living-vital Rinnegan he received is extremely far beyond thousand times more extraordinary powerful/capable than the half-dead Edo Tensei extremely weakened one.

It was like literally comparing the important significance of rarest diamonds to paper mache which is in shape of a common diamond and has some real microscopic pieces of common and rare diamonds inside. There is a lot of astronomical universal-sized difference here, both between real Rinnegan and Edo-Tensei Rinnegan and between Fully-Vitally-Revived Madara and the Half-Dead Walking Corpse Madara respectively.

Comment: You don't really give an explanation of the difference, you just mention that there is a big one - Can you maybe talk about that in your answer